# How to install apple safari without using wine?

Tags: software-installation

Being a web developer I would like to install Apple Safari to check the proper working of my code.

But I'm not getting how to install the Apple Safari on Ubuntu without Wine.

Comment: get hold of the source and code your own version of Safari. That's the only way. to do it in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Alvar That would work if Safari was open source. Unfortunately, it is not.

Comment: I know, my point is that you can't.

Comment: Is it very important to open sites using safari??? there are  very efficient alternatives such as Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: Don't ask him why he wants to use Safari, since he has already explained it. He is a web developer and want to see if his sites work on all "main" browsers. Like Opera, Safari, Goolge Chrome, Firefox etc.

Comment: if wine bothers you in some way, you can try a sandbox like: chroot, vmware, vbox (no need to have windows installed, on the virtual machines, install ubuntu and run wine there with safari; never tested that tho; I just cant see it not working :))

Comment: @BlackBlock my customer always uses apple tech. And firefox has just proven to eat 200% of cpu on 2 cpu cores on my 3 cpu cores vbox vm. I profiled this. All the code that ate 81% of profiled samples belong to firefox engine, not to user js code. And that made the host hardware overheat the package and cpu temperatures to 84 degrees Celsium. That's very efficient evolution of a working x86 into garbage bins.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no native Safari for Linux, so your choices are either use the Windows version and run it with Wine or in a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), or maybe run it with OSX in a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Yet another option would be to use another WebKit-based browser such as Chromium or Konqueror as a "close enough" approximation of Safari - they do run natively on Linux but, well, they're not Safari :)

Comment: Just a note that now Chromium no longer uses WebKit.

Answer (score 10):

There is no Debian package or any other linux package available for Ubuntu. Your only chance to use Safari on Ubuntu is use WINE.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the previously posted accepted answer.

Comment: @karel This answer was posted *three minutes* later, emphasizes Wine specifically, and has been judged valuable by the community with a score of +9 (as of this posting). [Answers like this, posted within a short time of one another, even with a far greater degree of similarity than here, are fine and can stay.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16793/22949)

Comment: The answer that was posted earlier also mentioned Wine, so that makes the two answers identical. My concern here is that you're ignoring the case when "judged valuable by the community" upvotes the later answer and downvotes the earlier answer which I've also seen happen before. This cruel situation would never happen if minimal standards of fairness were considered valuable too instead of "judged worthless by the community".

Comment: What do you think that one point sign-up bonus on all Stack Exchange network sites is all about? A new user is judged as valuable to the community for basically doing next to nothing, but instead of being awarded 20K reputation immediately, he only gets one point of reputation. As soon as he signs up the new user is bribed with one point of reputation to consider the idea that valuable to the community has some relationship to what the user does whether that is accurately reflected in the voting or not.

Comment: @karel *"The answer that was posted earlier also mentioned Wine, so that makes the two answers identical."* I don't think the word "identical" means what you think it means. Anyway, post scores on meta *do* establish policy consensus and I've cited the consensus that applies here. As for the rest of what you've said, it doesn't seem to really be about this post, and if you think there is a systemic problem with how people are voting, how posts are reviewed, or how the system is designed, I recommend posting on [meta] about it. That way your concerns will be noticed and might make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

You can install it via [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com) too

Comment: That's still Wine.

Comment: Right, I meant "POL takes care of dependencies so it's easier to use, if you don't like plain Wine" ^^

Comment: For your convenience, here is the Play On Linux downloads page https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html with install instructions and then you do `mkdir -pv ~/build/safari && pushd ~/build/safari && wget -t0 http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe -a wget.log && sudo apt update && sudo apt install wine-stable && wine SafariSetup.exe`. Credits and Thanks go to https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-safari-on-linux/ blog post.

Answer (score 0):

**BrowserStack**

One option not mentioned in the answers here are web solutions like www.browserstack.com, which let you view your sites/pages through a plethora of browser, display and OS combinations and versions. It's out of my league price-wise given how intermittently I do this kind of work, but there may even be an alternative competitor offering a free basic plan.

**BrowserShots**

Currently, I have a deal with my current client where they do the cross browser testing themselves so only if they find an issue (which they did today) do I need to consider this option. I'm currently evaluating http://browsershots.org as an option. It renders still images so you can't test interaction, but for my needs today it's ideal considering it's free (so far!).