# Is it possible to install Safari on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, wine

I would like to debug a browser compatibility issue with Safari. I don't have a Mac and Windows. I am interested if its still possible to install Safari on Ubuntu 14.04. I've tried using Wine 1.6.2 by installing the last version of Safari that works with Windows. While it installs, it does not launch.

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585209/opera-and-safari-installation) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83658/how-to-install-apple-safari-without-using-wine)

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't found anything that works reliably. I tried both @abdulla-nilam's WineTricks answer, and also PlayOnLinux. The latter gave better instructions but both ended up with the same result: An old version of Safari that crashes on half the pages I tried loading.

Answer (score 38):

Safari uses webkit as web browser engine. You can use `epiphany-browser` which also uses webkit engine for debugging and checking the compatibility:

```
sudo apt install epiphany-browser
```

Comment: much better than running a MacOS VM just to test on Safari

Comment: This MUST be the accepted answer to me ^^. Thank you @DanF

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Install wine

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
```

then load wine through start menu

> click - **Install an app**

[image: 01]

> Select - **Select Safari**

[image: 02]

> Click - **OK**

Comment: For future reference: The application from the screenshots in this answer is not `wine` but `winetricks`.

Comment: Thanks, @5chdn. To clarify, we need to run `apt-get install winetricks` and then `winetricks`, from the command line, to see the dialogues above. For me, it installed Safari 5.0, which blew up the first time I tried running it, but worked the second time. Unfortunately, my keyboard remappings don't work in it, but this is good enough.

Comment: ... actually, it crashes on half the pages I try to load. I might need to borrow a Mac from somewhere.

Comment: Note, that the latest supported Safari version for Windows (and wine) is 5.1, while we are at v13 since sept. 2019

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow has some answers but I am trying to find out if they're up-to-date.  EDIT: yea, they're out of date.  Safari on Windows ended when Safari 6 started.  Maybe it can be done legally or ethically in virtualbox.

(The remainder is wrong if you want OSX >=6.0) Basically, install Wine and possibly playonlinux, but I don't know if you can get Safari 9.  So far I just found out you can get Safari 5.  Here's a page of advice without a date on it.

Maybe one of these will work! Haven't tried it yet ....

https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-install-safari-internet-explorer-opera-on-ubuntu/  (without playonlinux)

http://thegeekdaily.com/install-safari-on-ubuntu/  (with playonlinux).

Comment: incidentally, found this too, in case someone needs to do debugging on an iphone or ipad:  http://blog.cordslatton.com/2010/11/debugging-ios-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone/  i will try to stop abusing the format now

Comment: Note that using Wine won't help - Safari for Windows has been dead for over a year, and I mean dead with no security updates or support... they stopped at Safari 5 or 6 I believe... so you lose a lot of features and support that you probably seek

Comment: I've been trying to find an OSX virtualbox for a very long time. ☹ Even Microsoft has worked out that if they want people to develop sites for their stupid browser, they need to make it free and easy to test on. No wonder so few of my clients care about Safari anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Apple Safari Installation in Ubuntu**

Firstly install PlayOnLinux, which allow easy installation of Safari in Ubuntu.
PlayOnLinux also enables the easy installation of several games and application designed to run with Microsoft Windows.

**PlayOnLinux**

```
wget -q -O- http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update

# useful dependencies
sudo apt-get install -y curl p7zip-full

# install playonlinux

sudo apt-get install -y playonlinux
```

Start PlayOnLinux
Start PlayOnLinux in the shell console and follow start up the instructions

```
playonlinux
```

**Install Safari from inside PlayOnLinux**

Select Button [+ Install] -> [Internet] -> [Safari] to install Apple Safari

Note!

1. The browser installation usually takes a couple of minutes because PlayOnLinux also has to download Safari.
2. The browser installation often hangs again and again! Just cancel and restart the installation from PlayOnLinux. Try, try again.
   You may have to restart 3-4 times until the final steps work without hanging
3. The installed Safari browser can only be launched from inside PlayOnLinux through the menu.

**Alternative Installation of Safari using Wine**

```
# install wine
sudo apt-get install -y wine

# create download and build directory
mkdir -p ~/build/safari
cd  ~/build/safari

# download
wget http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe

# wine
wine SafariSetup.exe
```

**References**

4. Apple Safari Home: http://www.apple.com/safari/
5. Guide: http://techhamlet.com/2012/03/how-to-easily-install-safari-in-linux-the-new-updated-guide/
6. Play-On-Linux: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/
7. Manual Download of PlayOnLinux: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html